# How to get rid of extraneous zeroes in dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this [list of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cckF.png) that I need to compare to another list that [doesn't have extraneous zeroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uXs.png). I would like to take the extraneous zeroes out of the first list. How can I do this easily? Would it be faster to convert the other list so that it has extraneous zeroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to remove all the extraneous **leading** zeros without using `datetime`:

```py
for i in range(len(date_lst)):
  date_lst[i] = '/'.join([x.lstrip('0') for x in date_lst[i].split('/')])
```

For the one-liners:

```py
date_lst = ['/'.join([y.lstrip('0') for y in x.split('/')]) for x in date_lst]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Shout out to Jacob too but I was hoping to avoid using datetime

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them into `datetime` objects. The `datetime.strptime()` function lets you create one from a string, where you also feed in the format of that date string. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime('06/13/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
y = datetime.strptime('3/1/2015', '%-m/%-d/%Y')
```

and then you can compare `x` and `y` with normal operators like `<`. You can also convert an entire list of strings like this via list comprehension:
`converted_dates = [datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') for d in list_of_dates]`

edit: you can also convert them back into strings with `strftime`, for example `x.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')` would give `'6/13/2015'`